# How shalL I expose S3 endpoint for clients to load files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I am running a project where in my clients upload the data file on my own server through SFTP.
Now the requirement is to move my application on cloud. So, I want those clients to upload those data file on my S3.

From design & security perspective, what are the approach or ways through which I can ask my clients to upload those files on S3? Shall I expose an application api (which will upload files to S3) to my clients or is there any other better & proper way to achieve this?

EDIT:
I would be uploading daily approx 200 files with each file of size approx 2-3 MB. These file uploads can't be scheduled, they are event driven. Our client SFTP the files as and when they need some processing of those files at our end.

Comment: How many files are they uploading? How big are the files? Do you wish to automate their upload (eg run on a schedule, or running an app), or do users need to nominate the files individually each time? Would you have any problem with them uploading via an HTML page? How do you authenticate the users? What do you want done after they have uploaded the files? (Please Edit your question to provide answers, rather than doing it in a comment.)

Answer (score 2):

If your clients are already using SFTP then you should consider simply migrating them to the managed SFTP service on AWS, which is part of [AWS Transfer Family](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-transfer-family/).

This will mean minimal change for your clients, and will allow you to shift their uploads directly into S3, which is ultimately where you want them to be.

Answer (score 1):

If all your service does is upload to S3 , Use IAM Users/Policies to grant access to s3 bucket to your clients instead as your service will act only as a proxy and add extra maintenance and costs .
If the data that you store on S3 is very critical , I'd suggest you look at this 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/security-best-practices.html#security-best-practices-prevent

However, there can be cases where you would want to expose an endpoint, lets say -

The client only requires the functionality to upload a file and no other operation. Here, the implementation is abstracted from the client and you can internally use or migrate to any other data store(be it s3) without affecting the clients. But consider this only if this is a possibility.